# NgRx Change State of Nested Object

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm learning NgRx and I don't know how to change a nested value inside the state's object.

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Money } from '@models/money';
import { setMoney } from '@actions/money.actions';

export interface MyState {
    money: Money;
    status: 'pending' | 'loading' | 'error' | 'success';
    error: string;
}

export const initialState: MyState = {
    money: {
        dollars: 10,
        cents: 60,
    },
    status: 'pending',
    error: ''
}

export const myReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(setMoney, (state, value) => ({
        ...state,
        ...state.money.dollars: value,          // How to access money.dollars and change it's value?
}))
```

In this example, how can I change the dollar or cents value of the MyState.money ?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd be better of using a library like `immer` to handle deep changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export const myReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(setMoney, (state, value) => ({
        ...state,
        money: {...state.money, dollars: value }
    })
)
```

To make things easier, you can also use [ngrx-immer](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-immer)

Comment: Thanks for the help! My program is fairly small and I won't be going that deep into nested objects, so I'd rather not need to use a 3rd party library but I'll keep immer in mind.